# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'href' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php, mysql

Getting error in this code...please help... i have changed it also like....

```
    echo "<td>" <a href="get_file.php?id={.$row['quote_id']. }">Download</a>"</td>";
```

or

```
<td><a href='get_file.php?id={$row['id']}'>Download</a></td>
```

still getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

(You don't concat the strings correctly and you forgot quotes for the href tag)

```
echo "<td><a href='get_file.php?id=" . $row['quote_id'] ."'>Download</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation is your friend when outputting HTML.

```
echo '<td><a href="get_file.php?id={'.$row["quote_id"].'}">Download</a></td>';
```

I usually try to put the single quotes on the outside and the double quotes on the inside because it's easier for me to manage.

Comment: i got the answer , but changed the coding with yours and got this error -> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'js' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: @AakkiRock - So you used my answer but accepted the other answer? I don't understand.

Comment: I posted above that i got the answer, still wanted to correct you thats why i posted about the error and he was the first one to give the answer also :) sorry anyway.

Comment: actually i am still having a problem, can you help me to echo in this pattern the above problem because the table format is not working now :|

in this way

      echo "<td>" . $row['size'] . "</td>";

Comment: I would recommend asking a new question, this one is already answered.

Comment: new question created, please check